# How to configure xvfb?

Tags: xorg

Could you please tell me how to configure xvfb in ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

I usually avoid configuring xvfb and just use the `xvfb-run`tool to launch applications into xvfb.

Answer (score 2):

Xvfb itself does not require configuration.  It is a command line application that takes in just a few arguments.

[See the man pages for a full description](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/Xvfb.1.html)

The most commonly overlooked thing when first running it is the format of the display number.  It needs a colon (:) in front of it (i.e. ":99").  99 also happens to be the default display number.  If you use the auto-assignment feature, it will count up from there when creating new ones.  The docs should help you with the rest.